# Karma launches and closes itself in chrome

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am testing Angular sing Jasmine and Karma.
The tests seem to run perfectlyand I am able to see teh results in the Windows console. But anyway is there a way to make Karma stay opened and not close itself after 2 seconds??

I have this configuration of karma.config.js:

```html
const webpackConfig = require('../../../webpack/webpack.test.js');

const WATCH = process.argv.includes('--watch');

module.exports = (config) => {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: './',
        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'intl-shim'],

        // client:{
        //  clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        // },
        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'spec/entry.ts'
        ],
        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [],

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            'spec/entry.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },

        webpack: webpackConfig(WATCH),

        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['dots', 'junit', 'progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul', 'notify'],

        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: '../../../../target/test-results/karma/TESTS-results.xml'
        },

        notifyReporter: {
            reportEachFailure: true, // Default: false, will notify on every failed sepc
            reportSuccess: true // Default: true, will notify when a suite was successful
        },


        remapIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: { // eslint-disable-line
                'lcovonly': 'target/test-results/coverage/report-lcov/lcov.info',
                'html': 'target/test-results/coverage',
                'text-summary': null
            }
        },

        // web server port
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: WATCH,

        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        // Ensure all browsers can run tests written in .ts files
        mime: {
            'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
        },

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: !WATCH
    });
};
```

And this package.json libraries included (thera re more but here are onl the ones that may be of interest):

```html
  "devDependencies": {
  "html-loader": "0.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.11",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.16",
    "protractor": "~5.3.1",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "source-map": "0.6.1",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "tslint": "5.5.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    ...}
```

Now Karma just launches itself for 2-3 seconds and closes again. Is there something wrong I have done in its config??

Answer (score 2):

Normally the CLI will run Karma with singleRun set to false which keeps the browser open. However with Angular 6.0 a bug was introduced where the karma runner no longer respects this default and does not run with watch enabled regardless of what you have in the config. There is a github issue for this here if you'd like to follow it and be notifed when a fix is released: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10711

In the meantime you can run it with watching enabled from the command line. Just use `ng test --watch true` instead of `ng test`.

So to sumarize, your config is okay, there is just a bug in @angular/cli@6.0.0 that will be fixed in an upcoming release. Until then you'll need to manually tell it to watch the code using `--watch true` flag.

Comment: But I am using angular 5!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in non-`WATCH` mode?

You have `singleRun: !WATCH`, which evaluates to `true`, I assume.

I bet it's not going to close, if you run this config in `WATCH` mode.

You can just set `singleRun: false` unconditionally.

Comment: Yeah, It does not closes now after I inserted:  autoWatch: true, and singleRun:false and I still see the results in console. But Karma is idle wthout results: Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 7.0.0) is idle. Debugging works by the way

Comment: @Tester So, I assume that Karma will run tests, if it manages to successfully create a webpack bundle with `'spec/entry.ts'` as an entry point. Can you check that webpack bundle is being loaded into the browser (in Chrome Developer Tools in Network or Sources tab)? Do you have `karma-webpack` middleware installed? https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/usage-with-karma

Comment: what should I see in sources of dev tools? There is one file named webpack/buildin and has a module.js inside

Comment: @Tester I assume, that's your webpack bundle. You need to make sure that the code of unit-tests that was generated from `spec/entry.ts` starts up. Maybe, set a breakpoint in your unit-test to make sure that it is reached and executed?

Comment: Yes it is executed beacuse I see teh results in my console perfectly. But in chrome when karma launches I see nothing.

Comment: @Tester No, this is not right. For me browser console displays test results.